# Select All text inside CellEditor

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I have a tableViewer where I can edit 1 column. Everytime the cellEditor from this column gains focus I want all the text that is displayed to be selected. In a normal SWT text control, we would just do `text.selectAll();` , so I've set this listener for the the cellEditor inside the column EditingSupport class:

```
editor.getControl().addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        Text text = (Text) editor.getControl();
        text.selectAll();
    }
});
```

I know I can cast the cellEditor control to a Text input because I've tested it with a normal `setText();` and it Works! However, the `selectAll();` is not working, how can I fix this?

**SOLUTION**

I found the error, the code in my question above works perfectly, the reason I wasn't able to see the `selectAll();` doing something is in this method:

```
@Override
protected Object getValue(Object element) {

    String valor = MathUTILS.getBigDecimalFormatted(((ColaboradoresDespesasDocumentosLinhas) element).getValor(), PatternVARS.PATTERN_BIGDECIMAL_MILLION);
    Text text = InterfaceFormatUTILS.getControlNumberFormat(editor, PatternVARS.PATTERN_BIGDECIMAL_BILLION);

    return valor;
}
```

This is also a method from the EditingSupport class, and for some reason formatting the text control (`Text text = InterfaceFormatUTILS.getControlNumberFormat(editor, PatternVARS.PATTERN_BIGDECIMAL_BILLION);`) deselects all the text. Also, doing the `selectAll();` in this method doesn't work..

Comment: Problem solved, see the answer for more info.